# How do I solve this error while attempting an SVN export using pysvn?

Tags: python, svn, pysvn

I am attempting to use the Python SVN bindings (pysvn) to do an export on a repository and am encountering the following error:

```
python: subversion/libsvn_subr/dirent_uri.c:955: svn_dirent_join: Assertion `svn_dirent_is_canonical(base, pool)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The example code is:

```
import pysvn
client = pysvn.Client()
uri = 'https://svn.mycompany.com/myproject/trunk/'
# This works fine
print client.list(uri)
# This crashes with the above error
r = client.export(uri, './temp', force=True)
```

However, doing a `svn export --force https://svn.mycompany.com/myproject/trunk/` from a shell prompt works without issue.

I'm using:

- Python 2.7.3
- Subversion 1.7.5
- CentOS 6.0 x64

Any ideas, please?

Comment: What if you try with absolute path instead of ./temp?  subversion/libsvn_subr/dirent_uri.c:955 line is assert(svn_dirent_is_canonical(base, pool)); so the problem is with path format

Answer (score 3):

Subversion API uses canonical URL and paths internally. You URL have trailing slash and this is not canonical URL. Remove trailing slash or use svn_uri_canonicalize() function to canonicalize URL before calling Subversion API functions.

You can find more details in Subversion API documentation:
[http://subversion.apache.org/docs/api/latest/svn_*dirent*_uri_8h.html](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/api/latest/svn__dirent__uri_8h.html)

Comment: Thanks for the great hint! In my case I had used `--config-dir` option with a path that ended with a slash, and that slash caused the assertion failure.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the `svn+ssh://` scheme and got the same error.  This lead me to believe that the assertion failure might not actually be related to the repo URI.  On a whim, I changed the export directory to `/tmp/` and everything worked fine.  The directory I was trying to use previously (`./temp`) exists in my home directory which is on an NFS mount with the "root squash" option enabled.  This has been known to cause odd application issues before.