# SVN crashing when cloning repository

Tags: linux, svn, archlinux

When I am trying to clone an SVN repository, SVN crashes as of a failed assertion.

```
[user@localmachine repositories]$ svn co https://svn.example.org/path/to/repository/
Authentication realm: <https://svn.example.org:443> Authorization Realm
Password for 'user': **********

svn: subversion/libsvn_subr/dirent_uri.c:1050: svn_dirent_join_many: Assertion `svn_dirent_is_canonical(base, pool)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am running Arch Linux on my machine:

```
[user@localmachine repositories]$ uname -a
Linux localmachine 3.17.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Dec 7 23:43:32 UTC 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

SVN is the newest version installed from pacman:

```
[user@localmachine repositories]$ svn --version
svn, version 1.8.11 (r1643975)
   compiled Dec 30 2014, 06:07:08 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

I did not find any valuable information about this when googling for it.

Is this a bug?

If yes, related to the Arch Linux build or the SVN version?

Should (and where) I file a bug report?

Or am I just missing something?

On antoher machine everything is working fine. On the machine it fails on it is also not working with HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Comment: As far as bug reporting, drop a note with *as much information as possible* to the [SVN users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/subversion_users).  Include versions of your SVN client and server, any configuration that might be relevant, and If it's a publicly accessible repository, the URL of the repository so others can more easily debug the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11637790/1023562) claims it is caused by trailing slash in your repo URL:

*Subversion API uses canonical URL and paths internally. You URL have trailing slash and this is not canonical URL. Remove trailing slash or use svn_uri_canonicalize() function to canonicalize URL before calling Subversion API functions.*

Comment: That didn't help. Same output.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, so i find the update in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SVN-4584 .
You can upgrade your svn package to 1.8.15